# Is there a way to compile a x86-64 golang binary on 2021 m1 macbook pro?

Tags: go, x86-64, apple-m1

I am thinking of purchasing a new macbook pro, but one thing bothers me, which is that I may need to compile the x86 golang binary on this machine and copy it to the other x86 machines, I did some search on Google, and it seems that Go support cross-compile, but anyone has the experience with this before?
Can I compile and get a x86-64 golang binary on the m1 macbook pro, which can be runned on the x86-64 machines with system like Ubuntu 20.04?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think Apple M1 will cause you any problem . 
Compilation for Windows :

```
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build hello.go
```

Compilation for Apple M1 :

```
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=arm64 go build -o hello-macos-arm64 hello.go
```

There is a great blog in [dev.to](https://dev.to) . I hope this will be helpful
[link](https://dev.to/tidalmigrations/how-to-cross-compile-go-app-for-apple-silicon-m1-27l6)